# Using an Increment Variable c++ Vs Using count++. Why Does One Fail To Compute While The Other Executes?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys so I was writing this code mostly for fun/practice. Its basic purpose is to take all numbers between two given values and compare them a counter that increments by 1 every loop to determine whether the pair of numbers is odd, even, or mixed. The two codes given below are identical save for one variable name in the check function. In the first code I used the variable c for the counter and in the second code used a variable named count.For some reason the first code refuses to compute but the second one runs. I was wondering why that is?

Here is the first code with variable c in the check function. This is the one malfunctioning:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>A Little Bit Of Everything</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function tr() {

var oddn = parseFloat(document.getElementById("oddnum").value);
var odde = parseFloat(document.getElementById("oddend").value);

var compare = check(oddn, odde);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = compare;

document.getElementById("output1").value = compare;
}

function check(N, E) {


var c = 1;

var statement = " ";

for (var i = N; N <= E; N = N + i) {



var outcome = ifcheck(N, count);

statement = statement + N + " and " + count + " are a " + outcome;

c++;

}

return statement;

}

function ifcheck(count, Ncount) {

var message = " ";

if (count % 2 == 0 && Ncount % 2 == 0) {

message = "even pair. ";

}

else if (count % 2 != 0 && Ncount % 2 != 0) {

message = "odd pair. ";

}

else if ((count % 2 == 0 && Ncount % 2 != 0) || (count % 2 != 0 && Ncount % 2 == 0)) {

message = "mixed pair. ";

}

else {message = "incomplete."}

return message;

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

This code is meant to check for odd, even, and odd/even pairs between a counter that starts at 1 <br>
and an number odd number that adds its own value to itself until it reachs the maxium counter entered <br>
by the user. <br><br>

Please enter in an odd number. <input type="text" id="oddnum"><br>
Please enter in a maxium number for the loop to reach. <input type="text" id="oddend"><br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="tr()">Calculate Pairs</button>

<div id="output"></div>

<input type="text" id="output1" size="400">

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the second code. It is identical except for the variable c being renamed count in the check function. This one works:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>A Little Bit Of Everything</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function tr() {

var oddn = parseFloat(document.getElementById("oddnum").value);
var odde = parseFloat(document.getElementById("oddend").value);

var compare = check(oddn, odde);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = compare;

document.getElementById("output1").value = compare;
}

function check(N, E) {


var count = 1;

var statement = " ";

for (var i = N; N <= E; N = N + i) {



var outcome = ifcheck(N, count);

statement = statement + N + " and " + count + " are a " + outcome;

count++;

}

return statement;

}

function ifcheck(count, Ncount) {

var message = " ";

if (count % 2 == 0 && Ncount % 2 == 0) {

message = "even pair. ";

}

else if (count % 2 != 0 && Ncount % 2 != 0) {

message = "odd pair. ";

}

else if ((count % 2 == 0 && Ncount % 2 != 0) || (count % 2 != 0 && Ncount % 2 == 0)) {

message = "mixed pair. ";

}

else {message = "incomplete."}

return message;

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

This code is meant to check for odd, even, and odd/even pairs between a counter that starts at 1 <br>
and an number odd number that adds its own value to itself until it reachs the maxium counter entered <br>
by the user. <br><br>

Please enter in an odd number. <input type="text" id="oddnum"><br>
Please enter in a maxium number for the loop to reach. <input type="text" id="oddend"><br><br>

<button type="button" onclick="tr()">Calculate Pairs</button>

<div id="output"></div>

<input type="text" id="output1" size="400">

</body>
</html>
```

Is c a reserved word or is there some other reason why one code works while the other does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code, You have declared the variable as `c` but used the variable `count` every where after that. You can get the first code working by replacing all `count` with `c`.

And **NO**, `c` is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: Gotcha. I replaced count with c and it work. Guess I was staring at it for two long. Thanks for the help!